# MuleSoft Google Calendar connector

Tags: mule, google-calendar-api, mule-component

Is there any way to authenticate Mule google calendar connector with google service account so that I can avoid the access popup every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my question

```
    public void Auth() {
    try {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
         credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(getConsumerKey())
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(getConsumerSecret()))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(getScope())).build();

         client = new Calendar.Builder(
                    httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(getApplicationName()).build();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Just include above function in the exiting google calendar code and remove the token based authentication from the code.
This will work absolutely fine with service account of google.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at Managing OAuth tokens, if you make the object store that handles these persistent, then it will reuse the access tokens rather than redirecting for authorisation each time: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.4/using-a-connector-to-access-an-oauth-api#managing-oauth-tokens-optional

Comment: still  after some period  of time the token gets expires  and  need to refresh, that will result in a pop-up screen

Comment: I am using the application in a automated system which generates events so I don't want the token based authentication, looking for service account authentication